# Having how many states is reasonable in TFS PBI workflow?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

My team is asking me to add all these states in the PBI workflow.

New,
Prioritization,
Design,
Business Review,
IT Review,
Approved,
Committed,
In Development,
Development Done,
QA Testing,
Ready for UAT,
Released to UAT,
UAT Testing,
Available in UAT,
Ready for Production,
Released,
Reopen,
Resolved.

I know that we can accomplish the same by using Tasks or Reason field and we have to keep the workflow "Simple" but my team is insisting to track that using a single field (State) so that it is clear. I would like to know if it is a good idea.

I appreciate your thoughts and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

We can't say how many states are reasonable or best. TFS is extensible and customizable, it is designed for customers will be able to meet the needs of the organization.

But as we know, the more states you define, the more transitions you must define. The maintenance and further upgrades will be more complex. Changing the workflow states of work items, specifically those in the task and requirement category can cause unexpected challenges in existing functionality as well as future upgrades. Changing to requirement types (Product Backlog Items and Bugs for Scrum, User Stories for Agile and Requirements for CMMI) will require modification of the Agile or Kanban board. They will also most certainly prevent an automatic easy template upgrade.

Customization should be well-thought out, instead of changing the existing State field, you may consider add a new "customStatus" field which won't impact existing reports and upgrades.

A good blog for your reference: http://blog.nwcadence.com/tfs-customization-pitfalls-payoffs/

Comment: Appreciate your feedback this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option for you to think about but you don't necessarily need to amend the states. You could use **Board Columns** which can be set on the Kanban board. With each column, you can optionally choose to split containing a **Doing** and a **Done** which could mean you require less states.

You can then query on **Board Column** instead of **State**

I was in a similar scenario to you when setting up our TFS (although not with as many states requested!) and I ended up going with Board Columns. Here is ours, it seems to work for us:

[image]

All of these have no split with the exception of **In Development** because when development is done it is not necessarily ready for test.

This functionality came with TFS 2015 Update 1 so you would need to upgrade if you're not on that version.

Here is how we use each state:

- **New** - New PBI or Bug
- **Approved** - Confirmed the work will be done and complies with the DOR (Definition of Ready)... (Contains enough info, priority assigned, tasks created, test plan created etc)
- **Committed** - Assigned to a future sprint
- **In Development** - Contains a **Doing** and a **Done**
- **In Test** - QA
- **Ready for Release** - Signed off and ready for release
- **Done** - Released and DOD (Definition of Done) has been completed.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I am currently in the process of upgrading my production environment. I upgraded our test server to TFS 2015 update 1 and I noticed the board column option and I was wondering what it was, now it makes sense. I will propose this option to our team and see if that will work. This would be lot easier than customizing the entire workflow and adding all those transitions.